# How to install Windows XP x64 manually?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, installation, 64-bit, mbr

OK so my question is simple I've a nice build of Windows 10 and OpenSuse and all my partitions are put in order which I don't want to risk loosing, letting about 10 years old OS managing those stuff. What I mean is that installing this OS will eventually do a lot of unwanted changes (like modifying my MBR to boot itself). Is there anyway I can simply 'extract' OS files from my installation disk and copy them over a new partition by myself?

I'm using rEFInd as a boot manager so latter I could eventually simply configure it to load the NTLDR file and boot directly without the need of writing an MBR record on my GPT disk. Is this even possible?

I don't like using VMs if you wondering about it.

Comment: One important thing to consider: XP x64 (unlike Vista, 7, and newer) does not use the AMD64 instruction set, but instead uses the IA64 instruction set used on Itanium server chips. Be sure to confirm that your CPU will support this before attempting install. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ia64

Comment: I've installed it before(on the same machine) so I don't think it'll be a problem.

Comment: @FrankThomas That’s not correct. The x64 version (as opposed to the 64-bit version) is made for AMD64.

Comment: I stand corrected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_Professional_x64_Edition

Comment: "Can Windows XP x64 read, write, and boot from GPT disks?
Windows XP x64 Edition can use GPT disks for data only." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn640535(v=vs.85).aspx#gpt_faq_xp64_boot